# MVC 3 - Can't resolve symbol 'GetUserErrorMessageOrDefault'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to create an HTML helper extension for MVC 3. I found some code on line that's got exactly what I need, but it won't compile due to this line.

```
string messageText = GetUserErrorMessageOrDefault(htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext, modelError, modelState));
```

The method GetUserErrorMessageOrDefault isn't defined.  Is this something that was in MVC2 that is no longer available?  Is there an equivalent MVC3 method that will do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question: [asp.net MVC - ValidationSummary not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545941/asp-net-mvc-validationsummary-not-displaying)

There's a code snippet that looks like the method that's gone missing.

Comment: Thanks.  That does seem to be the method I'm missing. I tried pasting that into my extension classs but it doesn't like the MvcResources.Common_ValueNotValidForProperty used in formation the message.  It can't find MvcResources.